# SQLite Beginner - PRINTING DIFFERENT ROWS FROM C.FETCHALL()

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my first project using SQL.

1. I `SELECT` the rows that I want: all the rows that have been entered between the entry of the searched row and + 1 hour.
2. Print all the rows of the previous `SELECT`: all the rows that have been entered between the entry of the searched row and + 1 hour.

Problem: When I try to print the rows only prints the row that I searched for and not all the rest of the rows matching the search.

1:

```
 if x.lower() == 'full name':
     specify_name = input('Please insert full name. \n ')
     select_query = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack WHERE NAME ==(?) ''', (specify_name,))
     information = c.fetchall()
     for row in information:
         print('\nName:', row[0])
         print('Email:', row[1])
         print('Phone Number:', row[2])
         print('Date and Time:', row[3])
         print('Venue:', row[4])
         print('\n')
         d = row[3]
         print(d)
         c.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM covidTrack
         WHERE datestamp >= ?
         AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')  ''', (d,d))
```

2:

```
general_information = c.fetchall()
print(general_information)
print('Matching Results: \n ')
for rows in general_information:
    print(row)
```

As you can see I tried to `print(general_information` before going trough the rows.
This is the output:

```
Name: Alejandro Trinchero
Email: Ale@
Phone Number: 11
Date and Time: 2021-02-10 16:34:37
Venue: nameofvenue


2021-02-10 16:34:37
[(4,)]
Matching Results:

('Alejandro Trinchero', 'Ale@', 11, '2021-02-10 16:34:37', 'nameofvenue')
```

I can understand by the `[(4,)]` on the output that `c.fetchall()` is getting 4 results but only printing one.

Any idea?

Full code for better understanding:

Comment: Typo: You're setting `rows` in the `for rows in ...` but then printing `row`, not `rows`.

Comment: @Barmar If I print `rows` instead of `row`. this is the output: `2021-02-10 16:34:37
[(4,)]
Matching Results:

(4,)`

Comment: Isn't that what you expected? `general_information` is a list with one tuple in it, since it's all the results of the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. The loop then prints each element of this, which is `(4,)`.

Comment: There aren't 4 results. There's one result containing the count 4.

Comment: @Barmar I was expecting all the results from the `datestamp` of the `SELECT` + 1 hour. I mean if the one that I `SELECT` was saved at 15:00, all the `ROWS` from 15:00 to 16:00.

Comment: Then don't use `SELECT COUNT(*)`, use `SELECT *` to get all the rows.

Comment: @Barmar That's perfect! Thank you very much, now I'm getting 4 times the same row. Quite head wrecking.

Comment: Again, make sure you're using the correct variable.